# Link to full site in Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, navigation

Is it at all possible to create a link in SFDC1 which will open the Safari browser and go to a specific VF page?  Or even just go to the SFDC login page?

Thx,
Hamayoun

Comment: From a record? Or from the hamburger menu/sidebar? Is there something about this VF page that keeps if from being SF1-ready?

Comment: I would think at least something would be possible because if you click on the icon right next to the map, it will open up google in your browser with the name of that record. However, can't seem to find out either how this would work. Interested to know in case you would find a solution!

Comment: When I click that icon it opens google, but inside the child browser rather than the native device browser, safari.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately it appears that there is no way to achieve this.  In theory, given that Salesforce1 is built on top of the mobile sdk, which in turn sits on top of cordova, we should be able to open a link in the web view, child browser or device browser (e.g. the external Safari browser on iOS), according to the cordova docs:

> var ref = window.open(url, target, options);
>
> ...
>
> target: The target in which to load the URL, an optional parameter
> that defaults to _self. (String)
>
> - _self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.
> - _blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
> - _system: Opens in the system's web browser.

However, attempting to use this mechanism with the _system target still opens the child browser.  As far as I'm aware this is due to the cordova configuration (which gives some additional control over this) that is part of the installed application and therefore not available to us to change.

Answer (score 5):

```
 <a onclick="navigate();">test</a>
```

I added the above small anchor tag in Salesforce1 and then used the below script

```
<script>
 function navigate(){
  window.open('/apex/ActionFunctionPage');
}
 </script>
```

And the above script opens a new window with Salesforce Full URL.

Comment: This opens in the child browser for me, not the Safari (external) browser.

Comment: Mohith, where exactly do you put that anchor tag?

Comment: I added that in a vf page

Comment: @BobBuzzard i thought user is asking to open in different child window only .

Comment: Mohith, we are 90% there.  This is working, and opening in a child window - thank you for that.  However, it is not opening in Safari, and this is then causing an issue.  What my VF page does is to redirect to a New Opportunity page with some of the fields pre-populated.  This (native) page has a lookup to the Account.  When I click on the lookup icon, it goes to the Account search page.  However, clicking on any of the Accounts  on that page does has no effect.  It looks as though the child browser does not support standard SFDC lookups.  Standard SFDC lookups work find in the Safari browser.

Comment: For your requirement i would say spent little effort and build a good jquery mobile page where you can provide a look up also in mobile friendly fashion

Comment: Yes there's a few ways we can do this, but right now our requirement is to get this working from SFDC1 without making any changes.  I'm going to open another question about the limitations with InAppBrowser.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12693/discussion-between-hamayoun-and-mohith-kumar)